# JSLint doesn’t expect my tildes

Tags: javascript, operators, jslint

JSLint insists that my use of the somewhat [exotic *tilde* operator](http://timmywillison.com/pres/operators/#tilde-useful) in the below example is unexpected. What I’m wondering is whether this is a limitation of JSLint? or strict mode? or what else am I missing?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    if (~'foo'.indexOf('bar')) {
        return 'wild accusations';
    }
}());
```

Also, why shouldn’t I use the simple-looking tilde operator instead of the more complex example below? Surely there must be a good reason not to?

```
if ('foo'.indexOf('bar') >= 0) { … }
```

Comment: Hey, that's something I didn't know.

Comment: You have to enable `Tolerate bitwise operators` (`~` is a bitwise operator). A reason why not to use it: I don't think it is that commonly used and is harder to understand (but that might just be me). It not only requires understanding of the operator itself, but also of the number *representation*, i.e. that `-1` is represented with all bits set to `1` (and therefore the complement is `0` -> `false`).

Comment: So since ~ is bitwise NOT, and in JS 0->TRUE !0->FALSE, and only ~-1->0 ... clever

Comment: Personally, bitwise seems weird here; why wouldn't you use `!` instead, since your goal is to determine true/false?

Comment: @Dave Newton It's not true/false.  `indexOf` returns -1 if the string is not found.

Comment: This is unlikely to cause problems in practice, but string character indices are not restricted to the range [0, 2**32) so `~` would fail when you have a very large string where the target occurs at power of 2 larger than 2**31, while ` >= 0` would not fail in those cases.

Comment: @Madbreaks Yeah, I know. And `!` booleanizes it. Which is true/false. If the condition is `>= 0` as in OP, you're checking for the presence of the string. That's a yes/no condition.

Comment: @Dave Newton You suggested using `!` in place of `~`.  That simply won't work. Perhaps you also meant "in addition to" using `>=0`?

Comment: @Madbreaks Not sure what I was thinking there; my truthy/falsey was hosed.

Comment: Thank you for spelling out "~" and making the question Googleable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [JSLint Docs](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#bitwise):

> ***Bitwise Operators***
>
> JavaScript does not have an integer type, but it does have bitwise operators. The bitwise operators convert their operands from floating point to integers and back, so they are not as efficient as in C or other languages. They are rarely useful in browser applications. The similarity to the logical operators can mask some programming errors. The bitwise option allows the use of these operators: << >> >>> ~ & |.

You can enable it under [options](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options%22JSLint%20Options%22)

Cheers

Comment: link not working, better update the answer with the solution