# How to fix the following errors

Tags: javascript, jslint

I implemented [spectrum color picker](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/), and I'm trying to fix up the JSLint errors. I have 2 types of errors which I can't seem to fix. Here are the errors:

> - Unexpected '~'
> - Unexpected 'in'. Compare with undefined, or use the hasOwnProperty method instead.

Here's the code for the first error:

```
function contains(str, substr) {
    return !!~('' + str).indexOf(substr);
}
```

Code for second error:

```
var hasTouch = ('ontouchstart' in window);
```

Comment: There is an option to tolerate bitwise operations in JSLint, should fix the first error.

Comment: You can use `(typeof(window.ontouchstart) !== 'undefined')` for second error.

Comment: For the 1st error, the option to silence it is `/*jslint bitwise: true */`. Info: [JSLint doesn’t expect my tildes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9473952) and https://jslinterrors.com/option-bitwise

Comment: As this is [the second question about jslint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167361/fix-error-in-spectrum-color-picker) in an hour my suggestion is that you read the documentation, particularly [the page on options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/). Note that these aren't _errors_ per se - they're _warnings_ that you can turn on/off depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function contains(str, substr) {
    return str.indexOf(substr) !== -1;
}

var hasTouch = window.ontouchstart !== undefined;
```

Comment: I think it should be 2 `==` instead of 3 at the `hasTouch` variable.